# VS Code search inside the editor without rollover

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I search inside the actual editor of VS Code without an match below the current line, VS Code rollover the search from the top of the page.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do instead of disabling this (which I don't thing this is configurable) is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. It's soft undo, **moves the cursor back to it's previous location**. This is particularly useful when you need to move down in a long file to copy a variable or function name and then go back to your original position. So when vscode goes to the top of the page, put the cursor there, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to go back to the previous line you where editing.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for... but this helps me a lot too!